# Is it possible to "UnNavigate" Frame (XAML element) which has been navigated already?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to "UnNavigate" the `Frame` element which has been navigated already. Is it possible? if I try something like this :

`MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Nullable));`

it doesn't work because `Frame` doesn't support type `Nullable`. So is there any other way to try to do this somehow? I cannot do the following `MyFrame = null;` because I lost the `Frame` element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One working solution is to do next: `MyFrame.Content = null;` . This one `UnNavigate` the `Frame`, or should I say that it just destroy all `Contents` of the `Frame`. Simple but effective.

Answer (score -1):

```
Frame.GoBack()
```

will take you to the last page.  Here is the API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.goback#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Frame_GoBack

Comment: I do not need to navigate previous page, I just need to "UnNavigate" frame. I found one possible way to do this: MyFrame.Content = null;

Comment: @Weissu Set Frame Content to null should be useful if you want to clear the frame content. If you mean you want this, I think you can just post your answer out and close this case.